# How to get a variable by another one in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I have three arrays in bash.

```
 arr1=(arr2 arr3)
 arr2=(1 2 3 4)
 arr3=(6 7 8 9)
 #How can I get a element of arr2 by arr1? like below:
 ${${arr1[0]}[0} # To get first element in arr2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eval:

```
eval echo \${${arr1[0]}[0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

An `eval`-less answer:

```
tmp=arr1[0]
tmp2=${!tmp}
echo ${!tmp2[0]}
```